# Signal handling in python-daemon

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, signal-handling, python-daemon

I installed [`python-daemon`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon) and now I'm trying to get the signal handling right. My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import signal, time, syslog
import daemon

def runDaemon():
    context = daemon.DaemonContext()

    context.signal_map = { signal.SIGTERM: programCleanup }

    context.open()
    with context:
        doMainProgram()

def doMainProgram():
    while True:
        syslog.syslog("pythonDaemon is running")
        time.sleep(5)

def programCleanup():
    syslog.syslog("pythonDaemon STOP")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    runDaemon()
```

When I start the code everything works as expected: The text *pythonDaemon is running* gets written to `/var/log/syslog` every 5 seconds. 
But when I want to terminate the daemon with `kill -TERM *PID*` the daemon is terminated but the text *pythonDaemon STOP* is missing from syslog.

What am I doing wrong?

NB: I am not working with `from daemon import runner` here, cause that gives me an error (looks like I need an older version of `lockfile`) and I will not fix this unless it is the only possibilty to get the signal-handling right.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code looks fine, except the signal handler is not called because it has the wrong signature. Make it like this:

```
def programCleanup(signum, frame):
```

Quoting the docs ([signal.signal()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.signal)):

> The handler is called with two arguments: the signal number and the current stack frame